# When I use a character chat networking library, why am I not receving the full string when writing blank spaces between words?

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, networking, c++14

The code doesn't print the blank space when I type it between words in the message `getline`, it only prints the first word or last letter, but if I write any character like `-./\_` between words, it will print the full message. For example:

-Without character:

I Write : `Hi how Are you`
I Receive : `Hi`

-With character:

I Write : `How-how-Are-you?`
I Receive : `How-how-Are-you?`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
using namespace std;

void server() {
    sf::TcpListener listener;
    listener.listen(5301);
    sf::TcpSocket socket;
    listener.accept(socket);
    cout << "New client connected: " << socket.getRemoteAddress() << endl;
    while(true){
        char buffer[1024];
        size_t received = 0;
        socket.receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer), received);
        cout << "Client : " << buffer << endl;
        string message;
        cout << "Enter Message  :";
        cin >> message;
        socket.send(message.c_str(), message.size() + 1);
    }
}

void client() {
    string consoleInput;
    cout << "Input server address: " << endl;
    cin >> consoleInput;
    sf::TcpSocket socket;
    socket.connect(consoleInput, 5301);
    while(true){
        string message;
        cout << ": ";
        cin >> message;
        socket.send(message.c_str(), message.size() + 1);
        char buffer[1024];
        size_t received = 0;
        socket.receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer), received);
        cout << "Server:" << buffer << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Client[c] or server[s]? " << endl;
    string consoleInput;
    cin >> consoleInput;
    if (consoleInput == "c")
    {
        client();
    }
    else if (consoleInput == "s")
    {
        server();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With `cin >> message;` the default behaviour is to skip over all preceding whitespace and stop when the next whitespace is found. You get one word with no whitespace. All of those empty spaces are discarded. If you want to grab a whole line, use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Tactical note: send and receive with TCP sockets don't promise to send or receive an entire message. Most of the time you have to check the return value to see how much was sent/received and keep looping around until everything has been sent or received. This is particularly tricky if you don't know ahead of time how much you need to receive. I think Remy warned you about this earlier.

Comment: And if he did, be careful deleting questions. A deleted question can never be upvoted and will never become a positive contribution to the site. Make too many non-positive contributions and Stack Overflow stops accepting new posts.

Comment: @user4581301 ok thanks you i didnt know that before ,i will improve my behaviour here.

Comment: No worries. Better that you know now than after you try to ask a question and get told that the server's "not accepting any more questions at this time." Once that happens it's extremely hard to dig out again. You get to ask one question every six months and those questions have to be very good to offset all of the zero-or-less ranked questions. If not, you're stuck waiting another six months. Rinse, repeat.